# PHP & sqlsrv - create array from results, without knowing column names?

Tags: php, arrays, sqlsrv

Using the below, I echo a JSON array of the results. But this requires that I identify the column names which I'd like to return from the SQL query:

```
$new_sql = "SELECT TOP 200 * FROM STracker ORDER BY [ID] DESC";

$check_statement = sqlsrv_query($conn, $new_sql);
$data = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($check_statement, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {             

$data['data'][] = array(

    'id'                        => $row['ID'],
    's_reference'               => $row['s_reference'],
    'reference'                 => $row['reference'],                                   
    'customer_name'             => $row['customer_name']

);                            

}
```

Is there any way to create that array information, but return all of the columns returned by the query dynamically? So by using **SELECT * FROM**, all of the column data is returned in the array but without me needing to write out all of these individually? (the below)

```
    'id'                        => $row['ID'],
    's_reference'               => $row['s_reference'],
    'reference'                 => $row['reference'],                                   
    'customer_name'             => $row['customer_name']
```

Ok I forgot to add that I'd tried this:

$data['data'][] = array($row);

Which is clearly wrong, and after using the following, it works perfectly!

$data['data'][] = $row;

Comment: `$data['data'][] = $row;`?

Comment: see I was doing $data['data'][] = array($row); and it didn't work, I'll try what you suggested :D

Comment: `$data['data'][] = $row;` that will work for you